# If $n\in N$ and $f(x)=\ln(1+x^{2n})$, then derivative $f^{(2n)}(-1)=0$.

Tags: analysis

If $n\in N$ and  $f(x)=\ln(1+x^{2n})$, then derivative  $f^{(2n)}(-1)=0$. 
I try: $e^{f(x)}=1+x^{2n}$ ,$(f'e^f)'=f''e^f+(f')^2e^f$ but I don't know what next.

Comment: Perhaps try induction? The derivatives should have some "regular" form.

Comment: That's the only try!